# HTML doesn't load CSS file

Tags: html, css, node.js

I created a local server to host html and css. HTML doesn't load CSS file. I don't see any error related to CSS in the console and the Network tab shows a 200 status for style.css

here is html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Developer Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar burger">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

here is server

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  let filePath = "." + req.url;
  if (filePath === "./") {
    filePath = "./index.html"; // Default file to serve
  }

  const extname = path.extname(filePath);
  let contentType = "text/html";
  switch (extname) {
    case ".js":
      contentType = "text/javascript";
      break;
    case ".css":
      contentType = "text/css";
      break;
  }

  fs.readFile(filePath, (err, content) => {
    if (err) {
      //errors
    } else {
      res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": contentType });
      res.end(content, "utf-8");
    }
  });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I also tried to clear browser cache, launch localhost from different browsers and my I don't have any folders for server or css files. All of the files are located in the same folder.

[folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mnjc.png)

Comment: If someone needs the solution. Just add charset=utf-8" in link tag so it will be     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" charset=utf-8"/>